# KeyListener doesn't respond

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, keylistener

I have written some code that makes labyrinth and fills the `JPanel` with my figures `Wall`, `Player`, `Road` and `Gate`. I want to move the player by pressing the keys <kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>.

The frame gets drawn but the player is not moving:

```
Sprite[][] spr = fr.read();
int x1 = fr.row;
int y1 = fr.col;
fr.close();
GameFrame gf = new GameFrame(spr, x1, y1);


x1 = (x1 * 20) + 30;
y1 = (y1 * 20);

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setTitle("Lab");
frame.setSize(new Dimension(y1, x1));
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(y1, x1));
frame.addKeyListener(gf);
frame.setFocusable(true);
frame.add(gf);
frame.pack();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setResizable(false);

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int a13 = 5;
    int a14 = 5;
    Player pl = new Player();
    super.paintComponent(g);


    for (int i = 0; i < i1; i++) {
        for (int i0 = 0; i0 < i2; i0++) {
            Sprite currentSpr1 = sprites[i][i0];
            X = currentSpr1.setXCoord(i);
            Y = currentSpr1.setYCoord(i0);
            H = currentSpr1.setHeight();
            W = currentSpr1.setWidth();

            if (currentSpr1 == pl) {
                addKeyListener(this);

            }
            currentSpr1.YourPaint(g, X, Y, H, W);
        }
    }



    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int c = e.getKeyCode();

        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            Y = Y - 20;
            System.out.print("lol");
            repaint();


        }

        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            Y = Y + 20;
            //repaint();
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            X = X + 20;
            //repaint();
        }
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            X = X - 20;
            //repaint();
        }

        //if (sprite instanceof Wall){

        //}*/

    }
```

Comment: What is `i1` and `i2` in the two for loops?

Comment: @Blip its rows and cols,so it run through the whole massive

Comment: Does `currentSpr1==pl` ever compute to `true`?

Comment: This question is asked daily. Start by looking at the postings found under the `Related` section on the right side of this page. Also, don't override paint() on a JFrame. Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(...)` of a JPanel and then you add the panel to the frame. Also don't add listeners to components in a painting method. The painting methods are invoked multiple times so you don't want multiple listeners added to the components.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit hard to understand your code, but firstly:

In your keyPressed method you're incrementing X or Y, but in your update method you're resetting X and Y, so this will have no effect.

And what's gf? Is it the class above. You should add "this" as a keylistener.

Comment: Can you please be more specified were do i reset my code?
I tried to add this,and it say you cannot add this in a static context

Comment: This is what I usually do:

Comment: You can add a class in frame.addKeyListener(); that implements KeyListener. If you write "implements KeyListener" after your class declaration eclipse will help you implement the methods you need. The you do frame.addKeyListener(this); Now each time a key is pressed the frame will call one of the methods in you class "this".